# Plot with points and "Reverse" axis

Tags: plotting

I have a plot with the abscissa reversed and I want to add a point.

```
Plot[1000, {Trev, 1/800, 1/500}, 
 Prolog -> {Pink, Point@{1/700, 1000}}, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Reverse", Identity}, AxesOrigin -> {1/500, 0}, 
 GridLines -> Automatic]
```

With the "Reverse" replaced by Identity it works fine.
Is there a way to add the point(s) in the reversed axis plot?

Answer (score 3):

> With the "Reverse" replaced by Identity it works fine

With x-axis reversed, the point will be at -x.

```
Plot[1000,
 {Trev, 1/800, 1/500},
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Reverse", Identity},
 PlotRange -> All,
 AxesOrigin -> {1/500, 0},
 GridLines -> Automatic,
 Epilog -> {Pink, PointSize[0.02], Point@{-1/700, 1000}}
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
Show[
 Plot[1000, {Trev, 1/800, 1/500}, 
  ScalingFunctions -> {"Reverse", None}, 
  AxesOrigin -> {1/500, 0}, 
  GridLines -> Automatic],
 ListPlot[{{1/700, 1000}},
  PlotMarkers -> Style["●", 10, Pink],
  ScalingFunctions -> {"Reverse", None}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also apply `ReflectionTransform[{-1, 0}]` to the coordinates of primitives in `Epilog/Prolog`:

```
Plot[1000, {Trev, 1/800, 1/500}, 
 Epilog -> {Pink, PointSize[Large], 
   Point @ ReflectionTransform[{-1, 0}][{1/700, 1000}]}, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Reverse", Identity}, 
 AxesOrigin -> {1/500, 0}, 
 GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image]